# Why is the general fiber of this map irreducible?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm going over the answer of whether an irreducible hypersurface of degree $d$ in $P^3$ contains any lines. We consider the set $\Psi = \{(V(F), l) | l \subset V(F)\} \subset P(Sym^d(k^4)^*) \times Gr(2,4)$. Consider the projection $\nu: \Psi \rightarrow Gr(2,4)$. Given a line $l$ in $P^3$, we can assume after a change of coordinates that $l = V(x_0, x_1) \subset P^3$. Then $\nu^{-1}(l)$ is given by the degree $d$ polynomials such that $V(x_0, x_1) \subset V(F_d)$, i.e. $F_d = x_0 G_{d-1} + x_1 H_{d-1}$ for two degree $(d-1)$ polynomials $G_{d-1}$ and $H_{d-1}$. So given such an $F_d$, its coefficients on the terms $x_2^d, x_2^{d-1}x_3,...,x_3^d$ are all 0. From this we can determine the dimension of the fiber, but why is the fiber irreducible?

Comment: Having coefficient 0 in front of a particular monomial is a _linear_ condition on polynomials, or equivalently on surfaces of degree $d$. So your argument shows that the fibre is actually a linear subspace of $\mathbf{P}((Sym^d)^\ast)$.

Comment: @user64687 By the way, how do we know that $\Psi$ is a projective set?